# Clojure CSV Matching Files

Tags: clojure, etl

I have 2 csv files with around 22K records in file F1, and 50K records in file F2, both containing company name, and address information. I need to do a fuzzy-match on name, address, and phone. Each record in F1 needs to be fuzzy-matched against each record in F2. I have made a third file R3 which is a csv containing the rules for fuzzy-matching which column from F1 to which column with F2, with a fuzzy-tolerance-level. I am trying to do it with for loop, this way -

```
(for [j f1-rows
      h f2-rows
      r r3-rows
      :while (match-row j h r)]
  (merge j h))

(defn match-row [j h rules]
  (every?
   identity
   (map (fn [rule]
          (<= (fuzzy/jaccard
           ((keyword (first rule)) j)
           ((keyword (second rule)) h))
          ((nth rule 2))))
    rules)))
```

f1-rows and f2-rows are collections of map. Rules is a collection of sequences containing column name from f1, f2, and the tolerance level. The code is running and functioning as expected. But my problem is, it is taking around 2 hours to execute. I read up on how transducers help improving performance by eliminating intermediate chunks, but I am not able to visualize how I would apply that in my case. Any thoughts on how I can make this better/faster ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `:while` vs `:when`

Your use of `:while` in this case doesn't seem to agree with your stated problem. Your for-expression will keep going while `match-row` is true, and stop altogether at the first false result. `:when` will iterate through all the combinations and include only ones where `match-row` is true in the resulting lazy-seq. The difference is explained [here.](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for#example-542692d3c026201cdc326fa7)

For example:

```
(for [i (range 10)
      j (range 10)
      :while (= i j)]
  [i j]) ;=> ([0 0])

(for [i (range 10)
      j (range 10)
      :when (= i j)]
  [i j]) ;=> ([0 0] [1 1] [2 2] [3 3] [4 4] [5 5] [6 6] [7 7] [8 8] [9 9])
```

It's really strange that your code kept running for 2 hours, because that means that during those two hours every invocation of `(match-row j h r)` returned true, and only the last one returned false. I would check the result again to see if it really makes sense.

### How long should it take?

Let's first do some back-of-the-napkin math. If you want to compare every one of 22k records with every one of 55k records, you're gonna be doing 22k * 55k comparisons, there's no way around that.

22k * 55k = 1,210,000,000

That's a big number!

What's the cost of a comparison?

From a half-a-minute glance at wikipedia, jaccard is something about sets.
The following will do to get a ballpark estimate of the cost, though it's probably very much on the low end.

```
(time (clojure.set/difference (set "foo") (set "bar")))
```

That takes about a tenth of a millisecond on my computer.

```
(/ (* 22e3 55e3) ;; Number of comparisons.
   10 ; milliseconds
   1000 ;seconds
   60 ;minutes
   60) ;hours
;=> 33.611111111111114
```

That's 33 and a half hours. And that's with a low-end estimate of the individual cost, and not counting the fact that you want to compare name, address and phone on each one (?). So that' 33 hours if every comparison fails at the first row, and 99 hours if they all get to the last row.

Before any micro-optimizations, you need to work on the algorithm, by finding some clever way of not needing to do more than a billion comparisons. If you want help on that, you need to at least supply some sample data.

### Nitpicks

The indentation of the anon fn inside `match-row` is confusing. I'd use an editor that indents automatically, and stick to that 99% of the time, because lisp programmers read nesting by the indentation, like python. There are some slight differences between editors/autoindenters, but they're all consistent with the nesting.

```
(defn match-row [j h rules]
  (every?
   identity
   (map (fn [rule]
          (<= (fuzzy/jaccard
               ((keyword (first rule)) j)
               ((keyword (second rule)) h))
              ((nth rule 2))))
        rules)))
```

Also,`match-row` needs to be defined before it is used (which it probably is in your actual code, seeing as it compiles).

Answer (score 0):

22k x 50k is over 1 billion combinations. Multiply by 3 fuzzy rules & you're at 3 billion calculations. Most of which are wasted.

The only way to speed it up is to do some pre-sorting or other pre-trimming of all the combinations. For example, only do the fuzzy calc if zipcodes are identical. If you waste time trying to match people from N.Y. and Florida, you are throwing away 99% or more of your work

Comment: Thanks madstap and Alan. Makes sense. I have to rework my algorithm. Sorry for not making it clear. I do need while. I only care for the first match. Then I move on with next record from F1 so I do need while.

Comment: @AmitShah Whoah, apparently I didn't know how `:while` works. Haha, that's embarrasing. Sorry about that. I think I can see a way to improve your algo, but you have post some sample data first.

Comment: He heee ! No worries @madstap .. I still get confused and trip all over the place with this. I am a java guy, experimenting with clojure ! I have been giving this a bit of thought, and a quick googling showed me   https://github.com/clojurewerkz/elastisch      So I am thinking about throwing in my F2 ~50K records in elastic search as documents, and tweak the mapping to return results, and see how that performs/goes .. It don't make sense for me to go so detailed into fuzzy matching/indexing area when my primary goal is just  to play with clojure and try to solve a real world problem with it